# Extracting files from partial downloads on Mac

Tags: macos, safari, data-transfer, file-conversion

I was trying to download my images from a website but got disconnected. Now I have few files sitting on my mac with names as:

> Camera Roll.zip-2.download (150 MB)
>   OneDrive-2018-06-07.zip.download (875 MB)

The file kind showing on the File Finder is Safari Download.

- I tried moving them to windows and removing the `.download` extension but it ain't working.
- I am unable to change the extensions on the mac. When I hit enter, unlike other files which allow you to edit the name of the file or the extension, these `.download` files have no impact. Entering enter doesn't allow edit. I then did Get Info. But the field wherein the name is mentioned is uneditable.

**Is there anyway I can extract images that were downloaded (if not all) from the above  partial downloads ?**

Comment: Hi, when i hit enter, unlike other files which allow you to edit the name of the file or the extn, these .download files have no impact. Entering enter doesnt allow edit. I then did get info. But the field wherein the name is mentioned is uneditable.

Comment: yeah true, just tried. I think in my case, it was a fully downloaded file so it worked.  (jut a tip: use @ to notify people. :) ) [tour] is a good intro for the site!

Comment: In **Terminal**, what does the output of the following _command_ look like, what do you see? `ls -alR ~/Downloads/*.download`

Answer (score 1):

You can't just change the extension on a .download 'file' & expect it to be seen as anything else, because it's not a file, it's a folder - or strictly, Package, like an app or your Photos library etc.

If you right click it & select "Show Package Contents" then you can see inside it - though if it'a a partial file there may simply be nothing to see. tbh, I don't know how it handles the contents internally, but they're not even visible with 'show hidden' switched on.

If you double-click it, or right click, Open, it will attempt to complete the download.

Comment: tried doing that. but there is no action. The source from where it was downloading is no longer active hence completing the download is out of question. What i was wondering is - since the file has contents in it, is there a software which will allow me to extract the contents?

Comment: Somewhere along the way, not sure which version of macOS, Apple made it so Finder could not see the contents of .download files, even if show hidden was turned on; however, one should still be able to see its contents in Terminal or with other GUI File Manager, e.g. muCommander.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what you do:

1. Select the .download file
2. Copy, Paste that file
3. Rename it to the desired file format (.mp4, .zip, .jpg, etc)
4. It becomes a folder.
5. Open it and inside you'll have your partially downloaded file.

You used to be able to do this by right clicking the .download and selecting 'Show Package Contents'. But now they made it harder to get there. Safety measures perhaps?